# R doRNG unable to find variable

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm running into issues running `dopar` inside a function, when registering `doRNG` and I need to access a variable that is created inside the function.

My overall goal here is to use `doRNG` to make sure my parallel processes get different streams of random numbers, so if there is a better way to do that, this will also solve my problem.

I'd be secondarily interested in why the using `doRNG` is failing, because I'm trying to understand how environments are exported to parallel processes.

The code here looks a bit contrived but this is summarizing a much larger and more complex code.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#if I comment out these two lines, code runs fine
library(doRNG)
registerDoRNG()

gVar <- 'gVar'

cols <- matrix(1:10,nrow=2)
res <- apply(cols,2, 
  function(col) {
    lclVar <- sum(col)

    res <- foreach(i=icount(2),
     .export=c('gVar'), #'lclVar'
     .combine='c') %dopar% { #change to %do% also works
       return(sprintf('%s %s %s',gVar,lclVar,i))
     }

    return(res)
})

print(res)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Note if I comment out the `doRNG` lines, the code runs fine. Also changing from `%dopar%` to `%do%` (and leaving `doRNG` lines uncommented) works.

I get the following:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'lclVar' not found"
```

Comment: Using `%dorng%` instead of `%dopar%` gives no error. Tried that?

Comment: @J_F actually that fixed my problem. So somehow the environment is not being passed in the same way when dopar is getting wrapped by dorng? Anyway that was a quick fix for the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My overall goal here is to use doRNG to make sure my parallel
>   processes get different streams of random numbers, so if there is a
>   better way to do that, this will also solve my problem.

If you can "rephrase" you problem as an `lapply()` call, then

```
y <- future_lapply(x, FUN, ..., future.seed = TRUE)
```

of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (I'm the author) will make sure each `FUN(x[[i]], ...)` call is done with a proper (L'Ecuyer-CMRG) RNG stream.  The future package also automatically takes care of global variables (e.g. `gVar`, and `lclVar`) being exported properly to each worker.

You can control how you parallelize with the `plan()` function, e.g.

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
plan(multiprocess, workers = 2L)
```

This works the same on all operating systems.

Comment: thanks for this great answer. The comment above from J_F was the quickest fix, so that is the best answer. However, your answer provides a nice alternative approach.